# Two fair dice are rolled. What is the probability that Their sum is $10$, given that the first roll is an even number

Tags: probability

For sure I am missing something but I am confused.

My reasoning for the problem is:
When the first dice is even, the only numbers that sum $10$ are $4$ and $6$, so the result should be $2/6$.

It seems that this answer is incorrect, so i must be reasoning wrong.  Any tip to put me ontrack?

Comment: even could mean that the first roll is a  2. you have to account for those events.

Comment: The wording is a bit confusing like it is the case in many probability questions! The accepted answer suggests that the desired probability is  P(sum=10 | Dice 1 roll resulted in an even number).

Answer (score 4):

Of the $36$ possible outcomes of a roll of two dice, $18$ correspond to the first die being even. Of those $18$, only two result in a sum of $10$, namely $(4,6)$ and $(6,4)$. Thus, your desired probability should be $\frac{2}{18}=\frac19$.

Comment: thanks.  I got stuck in the independence of the two events and assumed the first one already happened and as such as 1 * probability of the second event.

Comment: Thank you very much for inspecting my answer.